# Как сделать плавающую область?

Tags: javascript, html5

Как сделать плавающую область? Как например в ВК окошко, которое можно двигать и через которое можно отправлять сообщения находясь на разных страницах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Саму область фиксировать на экране через CSS:

```
.floatDiv {position:fixed; top:20px; left:150px;}
```

Но блок будет в пределах страницы. Вконтакт осуществляет навигацию по сайту аяксом. По факту, там все в пределах одной страницы происходит.

Comment: ага, ещё добавить драгабл, и крутую аяксовую навигацию для всех страниц

Comment: @Spectre, это материал выходящий за область вопроса ;)

Comment: я что-то не понял(((  я имею ввиду не тупо, что-бы он фиксировался от сторон браузеров, а что-бы блок можно было двигать в разные стороны, не только при скролле

Comment: гуглим **javascript drag and drop** и **javascript resize**

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui draggable - самый простой способ
http://www.linkexchanger.su/2009/107.html

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop, почитайте. Всё понятно и кроссбраузерно...